# In F#, are there any operations like 'melt' or 'cast' in R?

Tags: r, f#, reshape

Melt and Cast are popular operations to handle data in R. 
In F# that would be sequences of records of same type or something close to it.

Are you aware of any such functions in F#?

(If not, who would be interested in making some strongly typed version of them...)

**More information:**

Melt takes a table as input.
It has column title (our record fields), and a series of rows.
Those column can be grouped into a set of  'identifier' and a set of 'variables'

Melt puts this table in a new canonical form with the columns being now :
the identifiers, the column named @"variable", the column named @"value"

If you had 10 'variables' originally, like size, weight, etc.. you will have for each previous record, 10 records in the canonical form, with the values in the column @'variable' being filled with the title of the previous columns from your 'variables'

Cast, conversely, reconstruct a table from a melted one.

A short example in R, `melt` takes data (`dat`) that looks like this:

```
  a          b         c
1 1 0.48411551 0.2372291
2 2 0.58850308 0.3968759
3 3 0.74412592 0.9718320
4 4 0.93060118 0.8665092
5 5 0.01556804 0.2512399
```

and makes it look like this:

```
> melt(dat,id.vars = "a")
   a variable      value
1  1        b 0.48411551
2  2        b 0.58850308
3  3        b 0.74412592
4  4        b 0.93060118
5  5        b 0.01556804
6  1        c 0.23722911
7  2        c 0.39687586
8  3        c 0.97183200
9  4        c 0.86650918
10 5        c 0.25123992
```

`cast` essentially does the reverse.

Those 2 operations are **extremely** powerful on a day to day basis.
Once you have them it changes your thinking, very much like FP does.

Comment: Can you explain what they do?

Comment: Here's melt (not that it explains a lot: http://pinard.progiciels-bpi.ca/libR/library/reshape/html/melt-24.html) Cast has a bit more explanation: http://pinard.progiciels-bpi.ca/libR/library/reshape/html/cast-9g.html.  Of course that's not saying anything about what @nicolas is looking for.

Comment: Or a recent short overview here: (http://www.mathfinance.cn/R-reshape-package/)

Comment: I added a simple example illustrating what's going on in the R version. I hope that helps some.

Comment: "who would be interested in making some strongly typed version of them". I would but I don't understand what these functions are supposed to do.

Comment: @JonHarrop they do in-memory unpivot (shown lower). extremely powerful for massaging data easily, the package they are in was made by a R guy who can program (with a very functional mind). since his reshape package does heavy *type* transformation, this would be **showtime** for type providers. those beasts are next on my trophy list, if you don't beat me to it. When I find back that clear pdf for them I'll post it here.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `melt` is similar to SQL Server's `unpivot`, this ought to do the trick:

```
let melt keys (table: DataTable) = 
  let out = new DataTable()
  let keyCols, otherCols = 
    table.Columns
    |> Seq.cast<DataColumn>
    |> Seq.toArray
    |> Array.partition (fun c -> keys |> Seq.exists (fun k -> k = c.ColumnName))
  for c in keyCols do
    out.Columns.Add(c.ColumnName) |> ignore
  out.Columns.Add("Key", typeof<string>) |> ignore
  out.Columns.Add("Value") |> ignore
  for r in table.Rows do
    for c in otherCols do
      let values = [|
        for c in keyCols do yield r.[c]
        yield box c.ColumnName
        yield r.[c]
      |]
      out.Rows.Add(values) |> ignore
  out
```

Here's a little test to try it out:

```
let table = new DataTable()
[|"Country", typeof<string>
  "2001", typeof<int>
  "2002", typeof<int>
  "2003", typeof<int>|]
|> Array.map (fun (name, typ) -> new DataColumn(name, typ))
|> table.Columns.AddRange

[
  "Nigeria", 1, 2, 3
  "UK", 2, 3, 4
]
|> List.iter (fun (a, b, c, d) -> table.Rows.Add(a, b, c, d) |> ignore)

let table2 = table |> melt ["Country"]

table2.Rows
|> Seq.cast<DataRow>
|> Seq.iter (fun r ->
  for (c: DataColumn) in table2.Columns do
    printfn "%A: %A" c.ColumnName r.[c]
  printfn "")
```

which yields

```
"Country": "Nigeria"
"Key": "2001"
"Value": "1"

"Country": "Nigeria"
"Key": "2002"
"Value": "2"

...
```

Assuming `cast` goes the other way (i.e. `pivot`), you should be able to take this code and come up with a translation.

If you're doing this a lot, you might find it easier to load your data into SQL Server and use the built-in operators.

Comment: It looks like it is doing the same. Although I was hoping (dreaming) of a F# style, Seriously Strongly Typed version of it.

Comment: You need column headers to make this work, and since I don't know what types you're dealing with I used `DataTable`. I think you can take the logic and customize it to work with your preferred type(s).

Comment: I dont see how I can easily make melt type independant yet strongly typed. do we have to go the Type Provider way ?

Comment: Strong Types is better than Girlie Types

Comment: There are dozens of ways to approach this: pass the headers as a separate sequence, use indexes instead of column names, etc.

Comment: I will read more more about Datatable and its environment. Ideally, after melting and casting (sorry unpivot and pivot), I would have intellisense on the produced results.

Comment: what I find about strongly typed dataset seems quite complex. there is a TypedDataSetGenerator, that takes a Codedomprovider.

Answer (score 0):

> Are you aware of any such functions in F#?

There are no such functions in the F# standard library.

> A short example in R

Your example data may be written in F# like this:

```
let header, data =
  [ "a"; "b"; "c" ],
  [ 1, 0.48411551, 0.2372291
    2, 0.58850308, 0.3968759
    3, 0.74412592, 0.9718320
    4, 0.93060118, 0.8665092
    5, 0.01556804, 0.2512399 ]
```

and then "melted" like this:

```
let melt header data =
  let header, data = Array.ofSeq header, Array.ofSeq data
  [ header.[0], "variable", "value" ],
  [ for a, b, c in data do
      yield a, "b", b
      yield a, "c", c ]
```

Note that static typing requires that your "b" and "c" columns contain values of the same type because they have been merged into a single column.

> Those 2 operations are extremely powerful on a day to day basis. Once you have them it changes your thinking, very much like FP does.

I don't understand why. I suspect this is an XY problem and you are describing how problems can be solved in R when the same problem would be better solved using a more typeful approach in F# such as a map from "a" to a map from "variable" to "value" but without any idea of what anyone might want these functions for I cannot be sure.